# Refactor existing code to multi-threaded: download, convert to data frame, and save to database

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm working on refactoring a legacy code base that is single threaded. Currently, there are three objects:

- `DownloadData`: downloads json data from web resource
- `TransformData`: converts this json data into a pandas data frame and does all kinds feature engineering and cleaning
- `SaveData`: saves a that data frame to a database. This appears to have been abstracted in order to save to other kinds of formats but was never implemented?

Each of these objects is a subclass of `Do` and they have a single public method called `.do()`. Each of these `.do()` methods calls several private static methods in the class to perform each operation (like, authenticating to the web resource, getting the data, and converting it to json) and everything is well unit tested. At the end of each operation, it returns its final result. Right now the code kind of looks like this:

```
raw_data = DownloadData(data_to_download=request).do()
df = TransformData(json_data=raw_data).do()
is_saved = SaveData(df=df).do()
```

This works really well, but we'd like hundreds of these to happen concurrently. I have some familiarity with asynchronous work in Swift. My first approach without changing the code too much worked, but appears to work serially. At the end of each `.do()` method, I simply do `callable_method(item)` instead of `return item`.

```
completed_work = []

def did_finish_transforming_data(completed_df):
    is_saved = SaveData(df=completed_df).do()
    completed_work.append(is_saved)

def did_finish_downloading(raw_data):
    TransformData(json_data=raw_data, callable_method=did_finish_transforming_data).do()

for request in requests:
    dd = DownloadData(data_to_download=request, callable_method=did_finish_downloading)
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=dd.do, args=(request,))
    my_thread.start()

# Wait for work to complete
while len(completed_work) != len(requests):
    time.sleep(15)

print('We are done!')
exit()
```

I do know that what I did above is "multi threaded" in the sense that the thread ids are unique when printed, but they look like this:

```
$ Downloading Data, ThreadID: 1
$ Downloading Data, ThreadID: 2
$ Downloading Data, ThreadID: 3
$ Downloading Data, ThreadID: 4

$ Transforming Data, ThreadID: 1
$ Saving Data, ThreadID: 1
$ Item Completed, ThreadID: 1

$ Transforming Data, ThreadID: 2
$ Saving Data, ThreadID: 2
$ Item Completed, ThreadID: 2

$ Transforming Data, ThreadID: 3
$ Saving Data, ThreadID: 3
$ Item Completed, ThreadID: 3
...
```

Considering the requested `raw_json` are wildly different sizes, I don't think they should be behaving so serially. Some of the resulting data frames are a single row, others are thousands. I'm positive the 'solution' I came up with is not good, isn't 'pythonic' and is super gross.

Other things I have considered:

1. Not using a callable, and instead at the end of each `.do()` calling the next object in the chain. Would I be connecting to my db via `sqlalchemy` at the start of my `SaveData` class or should I pass a single engine to each thread?
2. Given that all these methods use this `.do()` logic, I feel like they would be pretty to convert to subclasses of `Thread`, but I don't really know what I'm looking for in terms of passing the end result from object to object within a thread object like that, nor monitoring their state.

In Swift, I would use an `OperationQueue` with a delegate that returns the final product. Each object would be a subclass of `Operation`, and just added to the queue by the delegate method. I'm obviously trying to replicate that pattern here, but I don't think it works.

**Where should I be looking given that I can't start this entire system over?**

Comment: In Python multithreading doesn't result in concurrent execution of the threads unless they're doing I/O or calling an extension written in another language — because of the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) — so what you're doing may not be the best approach.

Comment: Whoah! That explains why it runs serially. That isn't my experience in other programming languages so I had no idea. Should I be looking at `multiprocessing`?

Comment: Yes, `multiprocessing` provides true concurrency — it can involve a fair amount of overhead though, especially if there's a need to share a lot of data among the processes. In your case it might be best to store intermediate results in temporary disk files to minimize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try parallelpipe which makes use of multiprocessing
https://pypi.org/project/parallelpipe/

```
from parallelpipe import stage

@stage(workers=4)
def download(requests):
    for request in requests:
        yield DownloadData(data_to_download=request).do()

@stage(workers=4)
def transform(raw_data):
    for raw in raw_data:
        # you will need to pack your dataframe into a tuple
        # https://github.com/gtsystem/parallelpipe/issues/1
        yield (TransformData(json_data=raw).do(),)

@stage(workers=4)
def save(dataframes):
    for dataframe in dataframes:
         yield SaveData(df=dataframe[0]).do()

requests = ["url1", "url2", "url3", "url4"]
pipe = requests | download | transform | save

for result in pipe.results()
    print(result)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for this exact situation. Thank you.